# help with error: cant open device "\\.\COM6":Access is denied

Tags: arduino-ide, arduino-leonardo

I built a new pc which I use as a flight simulator. On my old PC I had ArduinoIDE for programming a pro micro as well as a teensy 4.1 using the teensyduino library. I installed all the necessary libraries and can make revisions to the code for the Teensy and successfully upload them. However when I try to upload anything to the arduino I get the above mentioned error.  The old pc could program the arduino without a problem.

The arduino is showing up in device manager and it disappears when the usb cable is unplugged. The correct port is chosen in the tools menu and I can get the board info. I just can upload it to the board. Still using  windows 10 pro, the same OS as on the previous pc.

Running the arduino IDE (v2.1.0) as admin does not help.

Comment: Are you sure the port number is correct _and_ not open by another program?

Comment: using usbtreeview.exe shows me the same info as device manager. The arduino is seen on com 6. I could post the output of usbtreeview but it exceeds what I can do in a comment and it is ugly. I just freshly booted this pc with only the arduino a keyboard and mouse as well as a hub connected.

Comment: Can you open the console window? Or does that print the same error?

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read "[ask]" to learn how this site works. This is not a forum. Therefore, you do not add new information or clarification in a comment. Instead, [edit] your question, and you have all features available, space and formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing Arduino 1.8.19 solved the problem. I guess v2.1.0 has some  code that trips over itself.